# Time independent Electric field implies constant energy

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

I have to show that for a time independent electric field $$\vec{E}(\vec{x})=-\vec{\nabla}\phi(\vec{x})$$ and an arbitrary magnetic field $\vec{B}$ the energy $$E=\frac{mv^2}{2}+q\phi(\vec{x})$$ is constant.

Where $\phi$ has an implicit time dependence from the motion of the paritcle $\phi(\vec{x}(t))$

I started  by calculating $$\frac{dE}{dt}=m\vec{v}\cdot\vec{a}+q\vec{v}\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$
and using that $m\vec{a}=q(\vec{E}+\frac{\vec{v}}{c}\times\vec{B})$ and $\vec{v}\bot(\frac{\vec{v}}{c}\times\vec{B})$
$$\frac{dE}{dt}=q(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{E}+\vec{v}\frac{d\phi}{dt})$$

The sum in the brackets should be zero for the energy to be constant but I don't know how the terms would cancel each other.

I would appreciate it if someone could give me a hint or some advice on how to approach this problem differently. Thank you!

Comment: you did something wrong, v.E is a sca;ar and v.dpsi/dt is a vector

Comment: Thanks, yea, just realized it too! I’m gonna have a look again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:  To take the derivative of $\phi(\vec{x}(t))$ with respect to $t$, you will need to apply the [multi-variable chain rule.](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/chainrule.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I think I got it now.